# I have extracted a widget and named it as ReusableCard ( It basically is a Container widget). Now I want to add GestureDectector to it

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my ReusableCard widget before adding GestureDectector to it :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const bottomBarHeight = 80.0;
const activeCardColor = Color(0xFF1D1E33);
const inactiveCardColor = Color(0xFF111328);
const bottomBarColor = Color(0xFFEB1555);


class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ReusableCard({required this.colour, this.cardChild});
  
  final Color colour;
  final Widget? cardChild;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colour,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
        ),
        child: cardChild
    );
  }
```

I tried and it worked by using required keyword.
I also tried using the late keyword.
And also to nullify the onPress Function by using the ? symbol.
But it didnt work as I want.

And this is my code after adding GestureDectector :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const bottomBarHeight = 80.0;
const activeCardColor = Color(0xFF1D1E33);
const inactiveCardColor = Color(0xFF111328);
const bottomBarColor = Color(0xFFEB1555);

class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  
  ReusableCard({required this.colour, this.cardChild, required this.onPress});        //I had to specify onPress as required.
                                                                              //But at some places I want                            to use ReusableCard without   
                                                                              //specifying a GestureDectection.

  final Color colour;
  final Widget? cardChild;
  final Function onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress(),
      child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: colour,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
          ),
          child: cardChild
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make `onPress` an optional, nullable parameter in the constructor, and return different widget if it is null. Also the declaration of the `onPress` functions should be `void Function()?`, and where you assign it to onTap: `onTap: onPress`

Also, if `cardChild` is not required, you will have an empty container, which is technically possible, but the user will see nothing. I would suggest to make it required.

Check out this code:

```
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ReusableCard(
      {required this.colour, required this.cardChild, this.onPress});

  final Color colour;
  final Widget cardChild;
  final void Function()? onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final container = Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colour,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
        ),
        child: cardChild);

    return onPress == null
        ? container
        : GestureDetector(
            onTap: onPress,
            child: container,
          );
  }
}
```